# How to show the current pshostprocess and runspace information?

Tags: powershell, debugging

When debugging a powershell DSC resource, we have a help from the DSC resource which shows the commands needed to attach the debugger to the right Powershell Runspace. As described in https://overpoweredshell.com/Troubleshooting-DSC/:
[image]

I want to be able to output the same kind of help from my powershell script, nothing to do with DSC.

So, how do I figure out my current PSHostProcess, AppDomain and Runspace Id from my powershell script?

I do not want to debug in ISE or any other GUI (for the reasons irrelevant to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process ID of the host process is available via the `$PID` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6).

---

The name of the containing `AppDomain` can be found via:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

but is usually not necessary when targeting most host applications (such as `powershell.exe` or `powershell_ise.exe`)

---

For the runspaces, use `Get-Runspace` from the host application:

```
Get-Runspace
```

Comment: What about the Runspace?

Comment: `$PID` is an automatic variable of the current powershell process, just clarifying terminology.

Comment: I know I am not asking it, but do you know how the script can wait for this debugger to attach? The `Wait-Debugger` command seems not to wait at all. I am currently idle looping with 1 second sleep in the middle, but there must be a better way.

Comment: @mark I'd suggest using VSCode to do debugging.  Setting breakpoints and debugging overall is a much more enjoyable process there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am still curious how to make script wait for the debugger the way DSC resource scripts do.